# Apache ODE deployed in a Jetty with reverse proxy. NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.xml.serializer.TreeWalker

Tags: apache-axis, reverse-proxy, jetty-8, apache-ode

I have deployed [Apache ODE](http://ode.apache.org/) in a Jetty Server with a reverse proxy.

If I go to `http://public-url/ode/deployment/services/` I can see the WSDL URIs for ProcessManagement, Deployment Service and Instance Management, like `http://private-url:80/ode/processes/DeploymentService?wsdl`.

If I click on it, obviously page is not found.

if I type myself the url `http://public-url/ode/processes/DeploymentService?wsdl` in the Server Jetty log I get:

```
2013-07-22 08:45:39.921:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/ode/processes/DeploymentService
org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.DataRetrievalException: org/apache/xml/serializer/TreeWalker
        at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.AxisDataLocatorImpl.getData(AxisDataLocatorImpl.java:84)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getData(AxisService.java:2195)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getWSDL(AxisService.java:1139)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1077)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:280)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:229)
        at org.apache.ode.axis2.hooks.ODEAxisServlet.doGet(ODEAxisServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:558)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:488)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:907)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:442)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:924)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:51)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:586)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/serializer/TreeWalker
        at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:823)
        at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema.serialize_internal(XmlSchema.java:264)
        at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema.write(XmlSchema.java:226)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService2WSDL11.generateOM(AxisService2WSDL11.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.WSDLDataLocator.outputInlineForm(WSDLDataLocator.java:131)
        at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.WSDLDataLocator.getData(WSDLDataLocator.java:74)
        at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.AxisDataLocatorImpl.getData(AxisDataLocatorImpl.java:80)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getData(AxisService.java:2195)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getWSDL(AxisService.java:1139)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1077)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:280)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:229)
        at org.apache.ode.axis2.hooks.ODEAxisServlet.doGet(ODEAxisServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:558)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:488)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:907)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:442)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:924)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:51)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:586)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xml.serializer.TreeWalker
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
        at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:823)
        at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema.serialize_internal(XmlSchema.java:264)
        at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema.write(XmlSchema.java:226)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService2WSDL11.generateOM(AxisService2WSDL11.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.WSDLDataLocator.outputInlineForm(WSDLDataLocator.java:131)
        at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.WSDLDataLocator.getData(WSDLDataLocator.java:74)
        at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.AxisDataLocatorImpl.getData(AxisDataLocatorImpl.java:80)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getData(AxisService.java:2195)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getWSDL(AxisService.java:1139)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1077)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:280)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:229)
        at org.apache.ode.axis2.hooks.ODEAxisServlet.doGet(ODEAxisServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:558)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:488)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:907)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:442)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:924)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:51)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:586)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

The exact same ode works fine when deployed in localhost so I discard the possibility of a missing Jar. Anything wrong about axis working with the reverse proxy maybe?

Comment: I assume it's a configuration issue (e.g. different JDK, other version of Xalan deployed, some other libs in the endorsed directory etc.)

Comment: @vanto, I have deployed the exact same jetty with same ODE inside in the server. Still same issue. Also I have tried with jdk7 on localhost which is the one server has and it still works on localhost...